# Why does odd.fst not work with the filter function?

Tags: haskell

Why does `filter odd.fst [(1,2), (2,3)]` give me a compile error? `odd.fst` should take in a tuple of ints and output a boolean, so I am confused as to why the compiler is telling me it can't match types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the same reason that `2 * 3+4` is `10`, not `14`. Operator precedence does not care about spacing: `2 * 3+4` parses as `(2 * 3) + 4`.

Similarly,

```
filter odd.fst [(1,2), (2,3)]
```

parses as

```
(filter odd) . (fst [(1,2), (2,3)])
```

no matter how you space it. This is because function application has higher precedence than any infix operator.

You want

```
filter (odd . fst) [(1,2), (2,3)]
```

instead.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you're getting a type mismatch compiler error is because the order of precedence is not as you're expecting. If you add more brackets then you will get the desired result:

```
filter (odd.fst) [(1,2), (2,3)]
```